# MMORPG networkconnection like Vindictus

Tags: unity, software-engineering, mmo, unity-networking, costs

to be honest, I like to make "small" MMORPG with my frends. We are 4 guys and are using Unity3D and Blender. I am a Programmer and I am using Eclipse. I know, it's silly to start a Question like "How to make an MMORPG like WOW". We want to make a very small MMORPG based on 4 levels (1 Town, 2 fields, 1 Dungeon). In the Dungeon you can join with max. 8 Person. In the fields you don't have to see other players. The one thing, I like to have is that in the Town you should be able to see all people who are in the town.

I never did network programming. Because of that, I have to hire sombody who would do the network programming.

Now my Question: How much does it costs, to make a game let you see each other in the town and to have a Texteditor who they can chat with each other. They can't trade and they can't do anything with each other in the Town.
In the dungeon they have a Texteditor too and they can all hit the enemy and the enemy lose health according to the last hit of player x.

Sorry for my bad english. I hope I have explained it good.

**I may have also another Question.**
How much do you think will cost the server for such a game? Unity Cloud would want for round about 500 600€. I dont thinks, that this is the normal pricing.

Thank you all and I hope you can help me. :)

Comment: The server sizing depends on the number of players and how much network and CPU load your game generates per player, so this is impossible to estimate for us.

Comment: the game have no more then 500 player at max

Comment: It's unfortunate this question was closed as too broad by someone who presumably doesn't know Vindictus and how it works, though your describing it as a small MMORPG probably didn't help^^

It might be too late now, but from someone who does know I can tell you that the town part is very simple and would not be very costly given your player estimate. 2-3 mid-class servers for $50~100 per month would be enough. And since Vindictus uses direct connection for the dungeons, you won't need to worry too much about the servers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no way to answer your question in terms of cost with the information you've given, you may be interested in looking at
Unity's [Unity Multiplayer](https://unity3d.com/services/multiplayer) which is free for up to 20 concurrent players.

Also available is [Amazon Lumberyard](https://aws.amazon.com/lumberyard/details/), which integrates with [Amazons GameLift](https://aws.amazon.com/gamelift/pricing/), which also has a free tier.

The price will increase as the number of player increases, but my advice would be to start small on a free tier and work your way up. If you reach more than 20 players then you can look to grow, but until then don't pay for bandwidth you don't need.

Both of these are good starting points, and hide a lot of the complicated networking problems for you, so you won't necessarily need a network programmer (which, for such a small game won't be worth the expense). Be aware that making an MMORPG is incredibly complicated and you would likely be better off with a smaller, easier to manage project to test the water with these products (such as a small co-op game)

Comment: thanks for the answere. But I am a little bit confused. Like I say: I don't have an Open world. I don't have a large World and the Interaction between the players is just the Communication. Is this rly to difficult to realize and more expensive as i can imagine? The "only" thing which is a MMO feature is to see each other and communicate via Textchat

Comment: I mean i realized once a live Textchat via PHP, Ajax and JQuery

Comment: You have elements of that in your dungeon though, right? People join together to fight monsters and in that interaction all sorts of problems with connectivity arise (what happens if the monster is dead after you registered a hit? can you see other players? what if you die after you hit, but before the server registers it?). It's worth starting small to get a handle on what some of those problems will be. Alternatively, start with the town and text editor (you can do this with PHP and [UnityEngine.WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) ), then expand up to a dungeon

Comment: ok. Thank you that you gave me a serious answere for my generall Question. :) We will do that.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :-)